# how to call email controller from another controller by passing some data

Tags: email, laravel-5.5

i want to send an email when a candidate applies for a jobpost on my site to the candidate.
my email controller

```
public function sendEmail(candidate $candidate, jobPost $jobPost){
    $company= $jobPost->Company;
    $name= $candidate->name;
    $email= $candidate->email;
    $job= $jobPost->title;
    $data= [
        'title'=>$company,
        'content'=>'this is sent by hrlead',

    ];
    Mail::send('email.test',$data,function ($message){
        $message->to('saberi1365@gmail.com', 'vahid')->subject('hello vahid');
    });
    return back();
}
```

my route:
Route::get('/email/{candidate}/{jobpost}', 'EmailsController@sendEmail');

i have an apply method which i want it to call the rout for it to send the email. but since i dont know how to return a dynamic url i am lost. 
so far at the end of my apply method i have put:

```
  return `redirect`('/email/' + $candidate +'/'+$jobpost);
```

which wont work

now i  dont know how to call the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is that you can extend your Email Controller from the other controller, then you can access all the functions of your Email controller.

`OtherController : EmailController`

Also

```
OtherController extends EmailController
```